# Getting new panel or tab to pop up

Tags: java, swing

I have a java application with a top panel, status panel, category panel, button panel, and a listDisplay all in a JFrame. I need a way to when a user clicks a button a new panel displays over all of the others where I can have some components or I need to put all of these panels into a tab and then have another tab for my search functionality. I just need a way to get a new page open to where I can implement a feature. Im not sure the best way to do this. My frame is a gridLayout(0,1).

```
mainScroller = new JScrollPane(btnPanel);
    categoryScroller = new JScrollPane(categoryPanel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(topPanel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(statusPanel);
    frame.add(categoryPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(mainScroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Did you have a look at `JTabbedPane` or `CardLayout`?

Comment: Yes I did, I wasnt sure how to get all of the panels into the tab. I also tried a card layout but Im not quite sure how it works, because only the first panel was visible.    cards.add(topPanel, "Card 1");
        cards.add(statusPanel, "card 2");
        cards.add(categoryPanel, "card 3");
        cards.add(mainScroller, "card 4");

        frame.getContent Pane().add(cards);

Comment: `I wasnt sure how to get all of the panels into the tab` - that sounds like you wanted to add all panels into one tab. It actually shouldn't be that hard to do, just call `addTab(name, panel)` to add a new tab (you also might want to revalidate the tabbed pane). Also remember _not_ to do any long running tasks on the EDT.

Comment: Yes, I want add all the panels but if I do addTab(name, topPanel) only the top panel is in that tab. If i wanted to add all of the panels to the same tab how would I do that?